# How to Fix "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias." in Python Discord Bot

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord.py

C:\Just_us_together\main.py:2: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses

import imp

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Just_us_together\main.py", line 57, in <module>
    async def help(ctx):

  File "C:\Just_us_together\Just_us_together\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1476, in decorator
    self.add_command(result)

  File "C:\Just_us_together\Just_us_together\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 245, in add_command
    super().add_command(command)

  File "C:\Just_us_together\Just_us_together\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1311, in add_command
    raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.
```

[This is Line 57](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz2ag.png)

I don't know How to fix these;-;

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It means is that there is a command with the same name or with the name in its aliases that already exists. You should probably post the code though.

Comment: How to post the code it has 600 lines.:-:::::

Comment: https://replit.com/join/zuqlaycagq-cakenomsod

Comment: you can fix it I've never used this site.:_;;;;;;;;;;;

Comment: When I change help in line 57 to H it's new.

Comment: I changed the name of the help command and the bot worked.